# Prevent specifying each integral value as unsigned in array-initializer

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, array-initialization

Consider the following function which takes a reference to an array of a size `N` deduced at compile time:

```
template <size_t N>
void array_consumer(unsigned const (&source)[N]) {
  // ...
}
```

I want to call it with an array initializer like this:

```
array_consumer({1u, 2u, 3u, 4u});
```

This works, but I don't want to specify the `u` after every value (the actual arrays may be much longer). Is there something I can do to the function signature or at the call site to avoid this?

Note that I need the array to actually be of unsigned type inside `array_consumer` (and I don't really want to make a copy) so changing the signature to `int const (&source)[N])` doesn't work.

Comment: There should be no need to specify `u` after every value. I assume you are using GCC as that seems to be the only compiler I could test that would complain about this. IMHO this must be a compilerbug as [\[dcl.init.list\] § 7.4](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#7.4) should explicitly allow this. Seems to be fixed in current trunk: https://godbolt.org/g/5gNwWn. The question is, of course, if updating or changing compilers is an option for you…

Comment: @MichaelKenzel - yeah, I'm using gcc 5.5, it hadn't occurred to me it might be a compiler bug! Changing compilers is not in the cards for a "minor irritation" like this though.

Comment: A pragmatic (text editor) solution: Write down your array initializer without `u` suffixes. Then select the whole initializer and replace `,` by `u,` (and fix the last value manually).